# Rails idiom for "unless foo.nil? or foo.blank?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a shorter way to write `unless foo.nil? or foo.blank?` in Rails 3.1? The check itself should not raise an error.

Comment: I think you should consider approving my answer instead. :)

Comment: @Qerub: I think you're right. Done!

Comment: It's a different question, but whatever.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you explain to me how it is different? They evaluate to the same thing. Is the "unless" phrasing more idiomatic in Rails?

Comment: @user1015384 The Ruby/Rails community *does* really enjoy `unless` usage (I find it confusing, almost always). It's different because they speak differently to the user. It's a matter of preference, and like I said, whatever--I assumed you were targeting `unless` because that's what you asked about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if foo.present?
```

15 chars instead of the 17 in `unless foo.blank?` and one boolean negation less.

Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F

Answer (score 8):

Sure; `blank?` covers `nil`.

```
unless foo.blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unless foo.nil?
```

is same as

```
if foo

Ex: "Foo is not null" if foo
```

Comment: They are not the same: consider the case that `foo` is `false`.